# open web services for Windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Learning developing for Windows store app now. A dumb question, wondering if we could open web services in Windows store app, so that other boxes can remote call the app remotely (call the Windows store app by the IP address of the box, where the Windows store app is installed)? If so, a guide is appreciated. Not found any good C# guide.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: you can not host a web service in a windows phone or windows store app.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I want to build kinds of a peer or peer, or a group-ware. What is your suggestion, pull information (using Web Services) from Windows store app? Thanks.

Comment: signal r.  http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2015/05/using-windows-10-uwp-app-and-signalr-on.html

Comment: @KenTucker, interesting post, do you mean I can use  SignalR (http://signalr.net/) in the Windows Store app to received message from outside (e.g. an external web services), so that I can communicate information to/from my Windows store app to external web services?

Comment: @KenTucker, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit people who has similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot host a web service in a windows phone or windows store app.  One way you can build peer to peer or group aware apps is to use signal r.

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2015/05/using-windows-10-uwp-app-and-signalr-on.html

Comment: Thanks for all the help Ken. Mark your reply as an answer. :)